# Combining different select sum queries with different where from same table (Laravel way)

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, query-builder, laravel-query-builder

I have slightly different select queries to read data from same table.

```
select user_id
     , SUM(credit_movement) as testing_fees
  from transactions
 where `type` in ('Testing', 'Testing Data') 
   and `user_id` in (118,124,352 ...)
group by `user_id`
```

```
select user_id, SUM(credit_movement) as production_fees 
from `transactions` 
where `type` in ('Production', 'Production Data') and `user_id` in (152,521,1341, ...)
group by `user_id`
```

The `type` and `user_id` are changing.

In Laravel, I ended up using 1 query for each type but there are 10 types which means 10 db connections - which is not good.

```
$values['testing_fees'] = \DB::table("transactions")
     ->select(\DB::raw("user_id, SUM(credit_movement) as testing_fees"))
     ->whereIn('type', ["Testing", "Testing Data"])
     ->whereIn('user_id', $userIdsToBeUsed)
     ->whereDate('created_at', '>=', $fromDate->toDateString())
     ->whereDate('created_at', '<=', $toDate->toDateString())
     ->groupBy('user_id')
     ->get();

$values['production_fees'] = \DB::table("transactions")
     ->select(\DB::raw("user_id, SUM(credit_movement) as production_fees"))
     ->whereIn('type', ["Production", "Production Data"])
     ->whereIn('user_id', $userIdsToBeUsed)
     ->whereDate('created_at', '>=', $fromDate->toDateString()) // this is common
     ->whereDate('created_at', '<=', $toDate->toDateString())   // this is common
     ->groupBy('user_id')                                       // this is common
     ->get();
```

What is a good way of **combining these queries into one query so that I make 1 database connection to get all data**?

(I'm looking for Laravel Query Builder way of achieving this)

Comment: `WHERE a OR b OR c`?

Comment: @Strawberry why is it gibberish; do you mean the 3 dots? I didn't want to put 500 `user_id`s there

Comment: @Strawberry, it's an obvious typo - it should've been `where type in ('Testing', 'Testing Data')`. I fixed it

Comment: @senty Do you have same conditions for every set of results except for summing with respect to type?

Comment: @nice_dev whereIn for type and user_id are different. In the last snippet you can see "this is common" comments

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to avoid confusion as to which is which, you can have a 3rd key which tells you what kind of data you are dealing with. Looking at [`Laravel docs`](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/queries#unions), your code should look like:

```
<?php

$values['testing_fees'] = \DB::table("transactions")
     ->select(\DB::raw("user_id, SUM(credit_movement) as testing_fees,'testing as type'"))
     ->whereIn('type', ["Testing", "Testing Data"])
     ->whereIn('user_id', $userIdsToBeUsed)
     ->whereDate('created_at', '>=', $fromDate->toDateString())
     ->whereDate('created_at', '<=', $toDate->toDateString())
     ->groupBy('user_id');


$values['production_fees'] = \DB::table("transactions")
     ->select(\DB::raw("user_id, SUM(credit_movement) as production_fees,'production' as type"))
     ->whereIn('type', ["Production", "Production Data"])
     ->whereIn('user_id', $userIdsToBeUsed)
     ->whereDate('created_at', '>=', $fromDate->toDateString()) // this is common
     ->whereDate('created_at', '<=', $toDate->toDateString())   // this is common
     ->groupBy('user_id');                                      // this is common


// and so on for $values

$query = array_shift($values);


foreach($values as $key => $sub_query){
    $query->union($sub_query);
}


$data = $query->get();

dd($data);
```

**Note:** The `->get()` only applies at the end after we have `union`ed all the subqueries.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the UNION keyword: https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_ref_union.asp

So the combined query will be something like this:

```
select user_id
     , SUM(credit_movement) as testing_fees
  from transactions
 where `type` in ('Testing', 'Testing Data') 
   and `user_id` in (118,124,352 ...)
group by `user_id`
UNION
select user_id, SUM(credit_movement) as production_fees 
from `transactions` 
where `type` in ('Production', 'Production Data') and `user_id` in (152,521,1341, ...)
group by `user_id`
```

If you need to allow duplicated, use `UNION ALL` instead of `UNION`

Comment: ERR_CONTENT_DECODING_FAILED 504. Anyway, you shouldn't simple put urls as an answer

Comment: well, then just search for the SQL keyword UNION, it looks like that's exactly what you need. It will just combine 2 sets of results with an equal number of columns

Comment: I just tried using union, however it combines the titles (the `as` parts) so I wouldn't know which is which

Comment: then add a 3rd column that will be different: `select user_id, SUM(credit_movement) as testing_fees, 'testing' as type .... UNION  select user_id, SUM(credit_movement) as testing_fees, 'production' as type`

Comment: Great! However I'm accepting the other answer as it's the laravel way. Thanks for your time

Comment: np, glad i could help